# authentication mode="Windows error by Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

> hi I had created Virtual Directory on **IIS7** to test the website on local host before deploying to end user I have this error on web.config "**authentication mode="Windows**"so where is the problem ?.

Comment: Sorry, But why did you add authentication as windows. I think I should run fine though, try running authentication as anonymous or form. It might help: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx"

Comment: I had this error  You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers

Comment: I recently developed a website, and tried this authentication mode there as well, but i didn't got any error. Did you set the permissions of the website in IIS, and try giving browse access to everyone in the security permissions. Just give it a try.

Comment: I created everyone user and add full control, but error authentication mode ="Forms" occurred again